# How to debug this angularjs error?

Tags: wordpress, angularjs, debugging

I am working on a Wordpress and Angularjs project on a Linux Mint 17 machine.

I managed to install the project correctly at my development machine at work, and everything worked fine.

However, I just finished installing it on my laptop using `git clone` from the same repo that I used at work. Everything went apparently fine, but when I try to load a certain page, it doesn't show up correctly. So I take a look at the Chrome Developer Tools console and this is what it says:

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/$parse/syntax?p0=%3F&p1=not%20a%20primary%20expression&p2=60&p3=%7BlineNumbers%3AshowLn%2C%20mode%3A'plaintext'%2C"<div class="CodeMirror cm-s-default ng-pristine ng-valid" ui-codemirror-opts="{lineNumbers:showLn, mode:'plaintext', onLoad:configEditor<?if(!$can_write):?>"nLoad%3AconfigEditor%3C%3Fif(!%can_write)%3A%3F%3E%2C%20readOnly%3A'nocursor'%3C%3Fendif%3B%3F%3E%7D&p4=%3Fif(!%can_write)%3A%3F%3E%2C%20readOnly%3A'nocursor'%3C%3Fendif%3B%3F%3E%7D
    at Error (native)
    at http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.16/angular.min.js:6:450
    at $a.throwError (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.16/angular.min.js:165:141)
    at $a.primary (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.16/angular.min.js:164:330)
    at $a.unary (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.16/angular.min.js:171:73)
    at $a.multiplicative (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.16/angular.min.js:170:310)
    at $a.additive (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.16/angular.min.js:170:170)
    at $a.relational (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.16/angular.min.js:170:34)
    at $a.relational (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.16/angular.min.js:170:111)
    at $a.equality (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.16/angular.min.js:169:397)
```

I am very new to Angularjs, so I really don't know what the problem might be or how to debug it.

Also, it is strange that I am using exactly the same code (`git clone`) that I used at work, where it works fine. So may be I didn't install something correctly? Browser incompatibilities?

I have already installed the Chrome extension Batarang but haven't found it useful (or dind'nt know how to use it properly).

**UPDATE:**
The error seems to be here:

```
<form class="contenido-evento">
    <textarea ui-codemirror="{lineNumbers:showLn, mode:'plaintext', onLoad:configEditor<?if(!$can_write):?>, readOnly:'nocursor'<?endif;?>}"
              ng-model="evento.texto"></textarea>
</form>
```

And this is the error message:

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '?' not a primary expression at column 60 of the expression [{lineNumbers:showLn, mode:'plaintext', onLoad:configEditor<?if(!$can_write):?>, readOnly:'nocursor'<?endif;?>}] starting at [?if(!$can_write):?>, readOnly:'nocursor'<?endif;?>}].
```

Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: will get more verbose stack trace output if you use development version of angular instead of `min`. Where's your code?

Comment: Thank you. I updated my post with more specific code and error message.

Comment: i guess reason is you are using html chars in your string

Comment: Thank you @HarishR. But what do you mean by "html chars"? How could I solve this issue?

Comment: `<?if(!$can_write):?>` this part... i dont know how would you solve, i have never used `ui-codemirror`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I managed to solve this issue by adding `php`. Like this:

```
<textarea ui-codemirror="{lineNumbers:showLn, mode:'plaintext', onLoad:configEditor<?php if(!$can_write):?>, readOnly:'nocursor'<?php endif;?>}"
    >
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

copy paste the first line of the error (which is http link) in browser, it will take you to errors.angularjs.org and there you can see the exact error

> http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/$parse/syntax?p0=%3F&p1=not%20a%20primary%20expression&p2=60&p3=%7BlineNumbers%3AshowLn%2C%20mode%3A'plaintext'%2C""nLoad%3AconfigEditor%3C%3Fif(!%can_write)%3A%3F%3E%2C%20readOnly%3A'nocursor'%3C%3Fendif%3B%3F%3E%7D&p4=%3Fif(!%can_write)%3A%3F%3E%2C%20readOnly%3A'nocursor'%3C%3Fendif%3B%3F%3E%7D

the error in this case is

> Syntax Error: Token '{0}' {1} at column {2} of the expression [{3}]
>   starting at [{4}].

i dont know what above error exactly is, but this is how i start debugging the errors...

Comment: Thank you. I managed to get a more specific message of the error and I updated my post.